# Hyperledger Fabric Explorer set up issue

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-explorer

I have set up my fabric network by official tutorial. Now I want to set up my first Fabric Explorer.

I follow this tutorial(docker version): https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/blockchain-explorer
I set up my config well, and `docker-compose up -d` is good as well,

```
$ docker-compose up -d
Creating explorerdb.mynetwork.com ... done
Creating explorer.mynetwork.com   ... done
```

but when I check my explorer by '127.0.0.1:8080'. It doesn't work. and I check my docker container.
My 'explorer.mynetwork.com' container status is
`Exited (1) About an hour ago`

and there is a error in the log is

```
$ docker logs explorer.mynetwork.com

\[ERROR\] FabricGateway - Failed to create wallet, please check the configuration, and valid file paths
{
"errno": -2,
"code": "ENOENT",
"syscall": "open",
"path": "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
}
[2023-08-31T07:46:01.623] [ERROR] FabricClient - ExplorerError {
  name: 'ExplorerError',
  message: '[\n' +
    "  'Failed to create wallet, please check the configuration, and valid file paths'\n" +
    ']'
}
```

Here is my env:

```
OS: Ubunut 20.04(WSL2)
go: go version go1.18.3 linux/amd64
docker:  Version:           24.0.5
         API version:       1.43
docker-compose: docker-compose version 1.25.0, build unknown
                docker-py version: 4.1.0
```

Here is my explorer directory

```
├── config.json
├── connection-profile
│   ├── org1-network.json
│   └── org2-network.json
├── docker-compose.yaml
├── organization
└── organizations
    ├── ccp-generate.sh
    ├── ccp-template.json
    ├── ccp-template.yaml
    ├── cryptogen
    ├── fabric-ca
    ├── ordererOrganizations
    └── peerOrganizations
```

Here is my config.json

```
{
        "network-configs": {
                "org1-network": {
                        "name": "org1-testwork",
                        "profile": "./connection-profile/org1-network.json"
                },
                "org2-network": {
                        "name": "org2-network",
                        "profile": "./connection-profile/org2-network.json"
                }
        },
        "license": "Apache-2.0"
}
```

Here is part of my docker-compose.yaml

```
explorer.mynetwork.com:
    image: hyperledger/explorer:latest
    container_name: explorer.mynetwork.com
    hostname: explorer.mynetwork.com
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=explorerdb.mynetwork.com
      - DATABASE_DATABASE=fabricexplorer
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=hppoc
      - DATABASE_PASSWD=password
      - LOG_LEVEL_APP=info
      - LOG_LEVEL_DB=info
      - LOG_LEVEL_CONSOLE=debug
      - LOG_CONSOLE_STDOUT=true
      - DISCOVERY_AS_LOCALHOST=false
      - PORT=${PORT:-8080}
    volumes:
      - ./config.json:/opt/explorer/app/platform/fabric/config.json
      - ./connection-profile:/opt/explorer/app/platform/fabric/connection-profile
      - ./organization:/tmp/crypto
      - walletstore:/opt/explorer/wallet
    ports:
      - ${PORT:-8080}:${PORT:-8080}
    depends_on:
      explorerdb.mynetwork.com:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - mynetwork.com
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

1. a clearly steps to resolve this issue.
2. the reason that causes this problem.